# tkinter buttons appear in another window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with the tkinter buttons. In fact when my first part is finished, it opens another window which proposes to play again or to close the window. But when this window is displayed, everything is displayed except the buttons that are displayed on another window. I also send you a screenshot of the problem and my code. Help me please!!
[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f909F.png)

```
def question():
global n
can.itemconfig(nvqst, text="Nouvelle question:", fill="white", font=("Helvetica", '11'))
if len(qst)<0:
     return
if len(qst)==1:
     fen2.destroy()
     a=False
     with open("score.txt","w") as storage: 
           storage.write(str(score))
           fen=Toplevel()
           fen.title("Quizz")
           can2 = Canvas(fen, height=400, width=600, background='grey')
           fichier=open('score.txt','r') 
           scorex=fichier.readline()
           image=PhotoImage(file='fin.gif')
           scorevarx=can2.create_text(330,200, text= scorex)

           def start():
               #exec(open("P:\Mes documents\projet bac\\test27.py").read())
               exec(open("C:\\Users\\Mohand\\Desktop\\python\\test27.py").read())

           can2.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor=NW)
           can2.create_text(377, 110, text=score, anchor=W, font='arial')
           a=Button(text='Rejouer', command=start, bg="#CDCCCD")
           a.grid()
           a.place(x=0, y=355, height= 25, width=605)
           b=Button(text='Quitter', command=fen.destroy, bg="#CDCCCD")
           b.grid()
           b.place(x=0, y=380, height= 25, width=605)   
           can2.grid()
           fen.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first parameter to each widget is supposed to be the parent window or Frame it is to become a child of.  You are passing this for some of your widgets, but not others.

Comment: And if you don't specify the parent, then the Widget's parent is the root window, the one that's attached to the Tcl interpreter.

Comment: I didn't know that buttons needs a parent parameter. Thanks a lot it works!!